# Typo3 6.2. cookie consent works only with German language

Tags: cookies, plugins, typo3

I am managing a very old typo3 6.2. website: [Gurtenhof](https://www.gurtenhof.com/de/gurtenhof.html)

I have successfully integrated a cookie consent banner from [Dp Cookie Consent banner](https://www.gurtenhof.com/de/gurtenhof.html)

However, the text from the cookie div in the right corner translates only for the German site and not for the Italian or English site. You can switch the languages at the top left of the website. It seems that f:translate does not find the other languages.

The languages are configured using:

```
[globalVar=GP:L=1]
    config{
        htmlTag_langKey=it
        sys_language_uid=1
        language=it
        locale_all=it_IT.utf8
    }
[end]

[globalVar=GP:L=2]
    config{
        htmlTag_langKey=en
        sys_language_uid=2
        language=en
        locale_all=en_GB.utf8
    }
[end]
```

Is there any way to pass the current language of the website to the plugin or any other configuration option which I have missed?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://docs.typo3.org/p/dirkpersky/typo3-dp_cookieconsent/main/en-us/Configuration/Language.html
Seems like you have to add them on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already tried this method without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language tags should be in the following form since the plugin directly takes them from the configuration:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
  page.config.sys_language_uid = 2
  page.config.language = en
  page.config.locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
  page.config.htmlTag_langKey = en
  
  config.sys_language_uid = 2
  config.language = en
  config.locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
  config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]
```

Then you can add all the different translations for the languages:

```
plugin.tx_dp_cookieconsent._LOCAL_LANG.en {
  message = This website uses cookies that are necessary for the technical operation of the website and are always set. Other cookies, to personalise content and ads and to analyse traffic to our website, are only set with your consent. We also share information about your use of our website with our social media, advertising and analytics partners.
  dismiss = Allow cookies!
  allow = Allow cookies!
  link = More info
  deny = Decline
  allowall = Allow cookies!
}
```

Nonte: Some of the special characters have to be masked using html entities.